# How to import existing android project into the eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I Checked out two projects from SVN(Server) both are related to each other, and i imported both to existing eclipse workspace but while launching the project, it is crashing at the home screen itself plz anyone let me know how to overcome this issue....

Comment: what is the error/crash message?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether it is a library project? If so then right click on project-> go to properties-> Android-> check weather the library project is added into your main project or not?

Comment: No pratik its our own built project

Comment: your own built project also can be a library. Put some log, what its saying?

Comment: ya exactly, put some log so we can understand better

Answer (score 1):

File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace, 
Next
Select root directory: /path/to/project
Projects->Select All

Answer (score 0):

If one of those projects is dependent on another, or is it's library, you will need to connect them somehow.
You will do that by right clicking on your project and then go to propreties.
There, it it's a library, go to Android and Add that project as a library.
Or you could go to Java Build Path and add a project there and manage your order and export